# Jquery add div with background behind text element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to place an absolute positioned div behind text some text or images. The reason I can't set the absolute div z-index to -1 is because there is content behind the text or images with background images. So the absolute div will be positioned behind that.

I am familiar with Javascript, jQuery, css etc. So what could I do to position the absolute div behind the text but in front of the background images?

Thanks!

Comment: Show us your code either in your post or in a jsfiddle.

Comment: You'll probably need to show us some code before we can give you a concrete answer, but it sounds as if you need to separate the element with the text and background into two elements (one with just the text, one with just the background). You can't insert an element in between 2 parts of the same element - think of the elements as layers.

Comment: Its hard to tell without your code, but try and set the z-index of the content behind the text or images to 1, set the z-index of the absolute positioned div to 2, and set the z-index of the container of the text or images to 3.

Comment: I thought that z-index only works on absolute elements. If not, then problem solved. If yes then if I make those elements absolute, then the other elements inline with the text/images will be off...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this maybe?

```
.div-1 { background-image:url(my-image.jpg) no-repeat 0 0; position:relative; }
.div-2 { position:absolute; z-index:1; top:0 left:0; }
.div-3 { position:absolute; z-index:2; top:0 left:0; }

<div class="div-1">
 <div class="div-2">behind</div>
 <div class="div-3">in front</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than setting z-index of div with background image to -1, create a div containing the images/text and set its z-index to 1.

Comment: Thing is... The divs containing the images/text are not absolute. If I make them absolute then the content that is in line with the images/text will be wrong... Get my dillema? :p